# I keep getting "We couldn't complete the features, Undoing changes" when I want to enable WSL

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to enable WSL on my Windows 10 and it's all fine until I get to the point in which I should do a restart to complete the installation, then it keeps getting me: `We couldn't complete the features, Undoing changes.` I'm using a X64 Windows 10 version 1909 (OS built 18363.1082). So what did I do about it? I kept getting the same error for updates for months whenever I restarted my laptop, and now I was getting it for both updates and features. So I thought it's a matter of coincidence and I got to Safe Mode, and deleted the last update there and tried again. This time it was no error about updates but: `They couldn't still complete the features` and it was really annoying. And yeah, I deleted my Software Distribution folder, enabled App Readiness, used CCleaner to clear registry, and disabled windows automatic updates. Non of them worked. Not at all. Tell me if I'm missing anything. That's all I know. Any kind of help is much much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem still. Did you find any solution to this maybe ?